Why was Zebulun-Issachar pact limited to the two tribes and more questions
The Midrash (B"R 99) describes the arrangement (Rashi calls it a pact) where the tribe of Issachar was engaged in studying the Torah (presumably full-time) and the tribe of Zebulun engaged in trade to support them.
So I have several small and related (?) questions regarding this pact:

Was this arrangement Jacob's order (within the blessing) or a voluntary arrangement between the two?
Why did only the tribe of Issachar decide to engage in full-time Torah study?
Why was his arrangement with the single tribe of Zebulun instead of all other tribes?
Wasn't the Torah study of the Levi'ites ("יוֹרוּ מִשְׁפָּטֶיךָ לְיַעֲקֹב וְתוֹרָתְךָ לְיִשְׂרָאֵל") enough for the rest of the tribes who provided them with sacrifices, tithes, etc?
Was Zebulun exempt from supporting the Levi'ites as they supported other Torah scholars (Issachar)?


Can anyone really answer these questions? The only way to find out is to ask Zevulun hiimself why he wanted to support Yissachar, and ask Yissachar why he wanted to learn and not "rely on the Levi'ites". Maybe wait til techiyas hameisim?
